# Canvas Jigsaw Puzzle - Animation While Joining Pieces

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I am trying make a jigsaw puzzle game which looks like this. What I have tried it looks like this. http://jsfiddle.net/Renjith_Rajendran/nx84ujop/2/

Now ,I need an animation while joining two pieces. How can i implement  this.

I am new to canvas and the pieces are moving out of canvas while dragging how can I limit that

I tried  to implement some effects here but not working

```
    add: function() {
        alert("Joining of Pieces");
        this.pieces = this.pieces.concat.apply(this.pieces, arguments);
        var i, l = this.pieces.length;
   for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
     this.pieces[i].border;
     this.pieces[i].strokeStyle = "#eee";
     this.pieces[i].lineWidth = 2;
     this.pieces[i].stroke();
}
```